# How can I get results without rows repeatitions

Tags: mysql, sql

Please, how can I perform this self join without all those duplicates?

SELECT t1.subject_id,  t1.score, t2.score,  FROM hs_results  AS t1 INNER JOIN hs_results AS t2 ON t1.subject_id=t2.subject_id
WHERE t1.term=1 AND t2.term=2 AND t1.admin_no='989'  AND YEAR=2020

[image]

```
 Base TABLE
R_id    Admin_No    Subject_id  score   Class_id     semester   YEAR
1       989          23         90       2            1        2020
2       989          21         60       2            1        2020
3       989          24         78       2            1        2020
4       989          23         100      2            2        2020
5       989          21         81       2            2        2020
6       989          24         87       2            2        2020

desired result AFTER self JOIN
R_id    Admin_no    Subject_id  t1.score    t2.score    Class_id    YEAR
1        989        23           90           100        2           2020
2        989        21           60           81         2           2020
3        989        24           78           87         2           2020
```

Comment: Can you please add the data and desired result as text? Just copy and paste it in your post, then select and press ctrl+K to format it.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. What are you actually using? The fact that you have tagged `mysqli` suggests the latter. Why is this tagged with `php`, are you looking for a SQL or PHP solution?

Comment: There is no `term` column in your sample data.

Comment: Please use modern JOIN syntax, available since 1992, that's 28 years now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what duplicates you are talking about.  But your `JOIN` seems to need more conditions:

```
SELECT t1.subject_id, t1.score, t2.score, . . .
FROM hs_results t1 INNER JOIN
     hs_results t2
     ON t1.admin_no = t2.admin_no AND
        t1.subject_id = t2.subject_id AND
        t1.YEAR = t2.YEAR
WHERE t1.term = 1 AND
      t2.term = 2 AND
      t1.admin_no = '989' AND
      t1.YEAR = 2020;
```